# Email sending properly without resque. But fails with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, resque

I am using resque_mailer to send emails from my application. This is my Mailer class:

```
class BulkMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Resque::Mailer
  default from: XXXX,
          reply_to: XXXXXX


  def bulk_email(email_id)

    @email = Email.find(email_id)

    recipients = @email.recipients.split(',')
    # => @email.recipients='sss@sss.com,sss@abc.com'

    smtp_header = {
      'to'=> recipients,

      'filters'=> {
        'opentrack' => {
          'settings'=> {
            'enable'=> 1
          }
        }
      },

      'category' => @email.subject
    }

    headers["X-SMTPAPI"] = smtp_header.to_json

    mail(to: 'cccc@ddd.com', subject: @email.subject)

  end
end
```

I am using Sendgrid's SMTP API.

All is well when I use normail Synch mailing. But when I enable resque mailer using that include statement in this class I get a failed message in resque-web.

It says:

```
undefined method `recipients' for 48:Fixnum
/home/steve/dev/rails/jm-sub/app/mailers/bulk_mailer.rb:9:in `bulk_email'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:459:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.13/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:453:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.4/lib/resque_mailer.rb:48:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.4/lib/resque_mailer.rb:48:in `perform'
```

This is how I call the mailer:
    BulkMailer.bulk_email(email.id).deliver

Again, It works without resque. I dont know what's wrong..

Comment: gUys anyone? I need help. I can seem to understand whats happening here

Answer (score 0):

My bad. :) I hadnt restarted the Resque workers after updating the code.

Restarting rails server didnt do the trick.